# How to infer the following graphs for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: classification, preprocessing, accuracy, data-analysis

I'm dealing with a high-dimensional(1600 features, 9500 columns) binary classification problem. My current accuracy, and other metrics are not upto the mark. I am trying different feature selection methods as well as well different ways to analyse the data such that I am able to achieve better results. These are some of the common graphs for my problem:

1. UMAP in 2D:

[image]

2. Manifold Learning Algorithms with their trustworthiness scores

[image]

3. Kmeans with t-sne dimensional reduction

[image]

The model I've trained and tuned so far on the test set has the following acc vs epoch:
[image]

The overall accuracy is around 90.5%, recall is 89% and precision is 94%.

We have a separate dataset for testing and validation. Also, I used Standard Scaler to scale the data before making these graphs. One more observation I have is the graphs do not change much even if I do extensive feature selection, and I can always see two clusters forming in the UMAP, one is the main cluster and other one is a smaller cluster which I believe is the problem.

Also, if you are able to make out some observations from these curves that I've missed is greatly appreciated.

I will share any visual graphs you would like to see. Thank you for your help.